# MYSQL: ¿Cual sería la forma más rápida de actualizar la hora de consulta de un registro?

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

En mysql un campo definido tal que:

```
logtime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Haría que cuando se hiciese un INSERT se plasmase la hora en este campo

y si añadimos:

```
ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

También se actualizaría este campo con la hora en un UPDATE

¿Existe algo parecido para un `SELECT`? Es decir, que cuando se consulte un campo se actualice un campo `TIMESTAMP`.

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta corta es que no; no se pueden establecer trigger en consulta -que sería la opción más obvia- y tampoco se puede hacer que se actualice un valor al consultar un campo.

Dicho esto, yo hice algo parecido para Oracle. Se trataría de lo siguiente:

1. Debes crear una vista sobre la tabla en cuestión, y todas las consultas hacerlas sobre la vista, y nunca sobre la tabla directamente: si tu tabla ya está en producción, bastará con renombrarla y crear una vista con el nombre original de la tabla
2. La vista debe tener una claúsula tipo where funcion() == 1 , donde función será una función que **siempre devuelve 1**, y que inserta/actualiza un valor en una tabla

Con lo que, cada vez que se acceda a la vista, quedará registrado a través de una llamada a funcion().